# Info lost between classes

Tags: c++, class

For one of my programming classes in c++, we are required to design a matchmaking agency and somehow after I create a new client it will add it in the operator's +=  to clients array, then in MENU class the database lost the client and I can't seem to find the reason.

**ADDING A CLIENT OPERATOR**

```
MatchmakingAgency& MatchmakingAgency:: operator+=( Client& c1)
{   
    if (m_clients)//Client** m_clients; 
    {
        m_length++;
        Client** newArr = new Client * [m_length];
        if (!newArr)
        {
            cout << " Memory allocation failed!" << endl;
            return *this;
        }
        //copy old array to new
        for (int i = 0; i < m_length - 1; i++)
        {
            newArr[i] = m_clients[i];
        }
        newArr[m_length - 1] = &c1;
        //delete allocation
        delete[] m_clients;
        m_clients = newArr;
        delete[] newArr;
    }
    else //m_clients is empty
    {
        m_length = 1;
        m_clients = new Client * [1];

        if (!m_clients)
        {
            cout << " Memory allocation failed!" << endl;
            return *this;
        }
        m_clients[0]= &c1;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

**MENU ADD A CLIENT //all client info from user **

```
{

    char temp[20];  //pointer to dynamically allocated data
    char gender;
    int age;
    int num_of_hobbies;
    cout << " enter ID number ->  ";
    cin >> temp;
    String id = temp;
    cout << "\n enter name ->  " ;
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(temp,20);
    String name = temp;
    cout << "\n enter gender F/M->  " ;
    cin >> gender;
    cout << "\n enter age ->  " ;
    cin >> age;
    if (age < 18)
    {
        cout << " Not in appropriate age!  " << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "\n enter number of hobbies ->  " ;
    cin >> num_of_hobbies;
    cout << '\n';
    char** hobby = new char* [num_of_hobbies];
    if (!hobby)
    {
        cout << "memory allocation failed!" << endl;//show message
        return;//go back
    }
    cout << "\n enter hobbies ->  " << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_hobbies; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(temp,20);
        hobby[i] = new char[(int)(strlen(temp)) + 1];
        for(int j=0;j<=(int)strlen(temp);j++)
        hobby[i][j] = temp[j];
    }


        Client cl1(id, name, gender, age, num_of_hobbies, hobby);
        m_data_base.operator+=(cl1);
    **//right here the m_data_base lost client info**
    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_hobbies; i++)
        delete[] hobby[i];
    delete[] hobby;
}
```

Comment: The whole point of overloading operators is that it lets you write `m_data_base += cl1;`

Comment: In your `operator+=` you are doing 1 `new`, but 2 `delete`s. Remove the `delete []newArr;` line. You need that memory that `m_clients` is pointing to.

Comment: Don't store a pointer you acquire with `&` for later use.

Comment: `m_clients = newArr; delete[] newArr;` is equivalent to `m_clients = newArr; delete[] m_clients;`

Comment: Your `Memory allocation failed!` error checking is pointless. `new` throws an exception when it fails to allocate.

Comment: @dan M. Haven’t learned exceptions yet

Comment: @Abby well, why are you checking the result of the `new` then? It won't ever return `nullptr` (there is a special overload that has these semantics, but you'll get to it in your class). Also, unless that's the requirement of your class, "naked" new a delete are never a good idea. It's easy to make a mistake (as demonstrated by you) and pain to deal with. If you are allowed to use STL classes like `std::vector`, use them.

Comment: I deleted that line, didn’t help much, still loosing client info tried debugging it million times I wrote where exactly the debugger shows it’s lost @Dan M.

Comment: @Abby and it shouldn't. Anyway, what do you mean by `right here the m_data_base lost client info`? How do yo determine that it "lost" something and that happened right there? Also, there is almost guaranteed dangling pointer in your case because you store the address of the Client created on the stack which will be destroyed when you leave your second function. There are a lot of things just screaming bad practice about this code. Why do you want to store everything as pointers/naked array/naked arrays of pointers? Is it a requirement of your programming class? The less allocation the better.

Comment: yes that is required in class(the more allocation the better) anyway I fixed it so the operator+=  gets a copy of the client and not by reference, I followed the debugger that's how I know where info is "falling between classes". @DanM.

Comment: If you still take the address of that copy - you have the same problem. It gets destroyed after it goes out of scope. You didn't explain what you count as info "falling between classes". If you are on linux or macos, I bet that running your program through valgrind or with memory sanitizer would highlight a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've copied the client pointers over to newArr, adding in the new one, then after setting m_clients to the newArr pointer you delete everything you just copied by deleting the newArr pointer.

```
    delete[] m_clients;
    m_clients = newArr;
    delete[] newArr;
```

Comment: So I have to copy it with for loop? Then delete?@sanchrp

Comment: No as they've said above, don't delete you're newArr pointer, it's stocked in the m_clients member variable.  If the function were continuing and you wanted to be sure not to do anything silly you could set the newArr to nullptr to avoid modifying m_clients indirectly but in this case just remove the line.

Comment: I deleted that line, didn’t help much, still loosing client info tried debugging it million times I wrote where exactly the debugger shows it’s lost @sanchrp

Comment: You've got another problem.  You're passing a local variable(stack) to the += operator as a reference then you stock the pointer of that client which is deallocated at the end of the menu add function or earlier if the optimizer judges it no longer necessary.  You need to allocate a new Client on the heap for your Client and copy the argument into it.